# JTabbedPane Malfunctioning

Tags: java, jtabbedpane

I have a problem with my code. I am trying to get into user interfaces in Java, and have started using JOptionPane. At the moment, I'm experimenting with JTabbedPane, but I have a problem with it. My problem is the following: when I try to run the code, so that a panel with one tab appears reading 'You are using the program "CarDealership".', nothing happens. I don't know what's the problem, but my terminal reads the following when I compile and run my program...:

Terminal...: [TerminalOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g37o3.png)

My code...: [ProgramCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCVp0.png)

I'm coding in Visual Studio Code, and, as you can tell by reviewing the code, I am from México. I translated the variables used in the program in a comment. Thank you for reading!

Code in text...:

```
/*

The name of the program translates to 'ProgCarDealership'.

Variables used...:
Example: 'Type/NameInSpanish/NameInEnglish'

- JTabbedPane/Pestañas/Tabs
- JLabel/Contenido/Content
- JPanel/Pestaña1/Tab1

*/

import javax.swing.*;
public class ProgLoteDeCarros extends JFrame
{
public VentanaPrincipal()
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    setVisible(true);
    setTitle("Programa Lote de Carros");

    JTabbedPane Pestañas = new JTabbedPane();

    JPanel Pestaña1 = new JPanel();
    JLabel Contenido = new JLabel ("Estas usando el programa 'Lote de Carros'.");
    Pestaña1.add(Contenido);
    Pestañas.addTab("Información", Pestaña1);

    getContentPane().add(Pestañas);

}

public static void main (String [] Yoshi)
{
    ProgLoteDeCarros VentanaPrincipal = new ProgLoteDeCarros();
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code and terminal in text format inside your post. Also, move `setVisible(true)` to the very end of your constructor method below where you add contents to the JFrame.

Comment: The post now contains my code.

Comment: I'm not sure how it is supposed to look; when I run the code, I get this: [https://imgur.com/qxcdiFF](https://imgur.com/qxcdiFF). Is your result different than mine, or how should it be different compared to this?

Comment: The name of the constructor has to be the same as the name of the class. Rather than `VentanaPrincipal()` shouldn't that be `ProgLoteDeCarros()` ?

Comment: Answer to @mega12345mega: Yes! My result is totally different from yours. In my case, the window does NOT appear, even though we have the same code. That makes me think that the problem is not related to the code; it's related to my Visual Studio Code program. Thank you so much for helping me out!



EDIT: I made the program work thanks to your code and Abra's help! Thank you so much, everyone!

Comment: Answer to @Abra: I don't think that's the problem. I think the problem has to do with something related to my Visual Studio Code. Any suggestions on what I could possibly do to get the program working? Also, thank you for your reply!

Comment: You code does not compile because of this line: `public VentanaPrincipal()` so how can you say it's not the problem? If your code does compile then the problem is with your IDE - which you claim is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). Or maybe the code in your question is not your actual code? For your information, when I fixed the incorrect constructor and ran your code, it displayed the GUI as intended.